# Divide column A when Greater than Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I accomplish this task using T-Sql:
If column A > 0,(B/A) *100 ?

Basically, I am checking that column A is not equal to 0 before dividing column B by a so I do not get error.
Thank you

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you have a query or a procedure? What if it is `0`. Select something else?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230041/how-to-protect-sql-statement-from-divide-by-zero-error

Comment: When you ask next time, please share us, what did you tried so far, what kind of research or internet search did you to solve the problem by yourself. Also please provide some additional information what is the exact problem, or what we should clarify to help you to solve your problem. Some code snippets from your failed attempts also could help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using a case statement

```
Case when A > 0 then B/A*100
else 0 end as yourfield
```

This assumes that you want 0 displayed when A is not > 0.

However consideration needs to be given if A could be negative, do you want to allow that division to occur?  If so then you need to only consider when A is 0.

Answer (score 2):

In T-SQL, you would probably want to do:

```
select (case when A <> 0 then 100 * B / cast(A as float)
        end)
```

This will return `NULL` in the event that `A` is `0`.  That seems reasonable to me.

Notes:

- You can replace `<>` with `>` if you only want to consider positive values of `A`.
- Note the conversion of `A` to a non-integer representation.  SQL Server does integer division, so if both are integers, then the result is only an integer (i.e. if A < B and A >= 0, then the result is `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Another idea can be the "IFNULL" clause.

```
SELECT (0 / NULLIF(@yourVariable,0))
SELECT (NULLIF(@yourVariable,0)/0)
```

*Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.*

This is one example with your task:

```
DECLARE @variableA INT SET @variableA = 0
DECLARE @variableB INT SET @variableB = 50
SELECT  (@variableB / NULLIF(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),@variableA),0)) * 100
```

---

For more information and more examples you can visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For example we have:

```
 Select ( 10/ 0 ) AS value
```

You must change it to:

```
 Select ( 10 / NULLIF( 0, 0 ) ) AS value
```